# docker webserver can't find file to mount

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, deployment, devops

**I just need to deploy and add ssl so I used this [ref](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose). so if you have any ref to an another solution, please put it.**
I've a nodejs website I'm trying to deploy with docker and add ssl certificate
but when i do ***docker-compose up*** I get this error:

> can't mount "website-opt/views/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/websiteopt_web-root/_data" ... file doesn't exist

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install --production

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    
    networks:
      - app-network
  webserver:
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'

    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command:
      certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email
      domain@mail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d
      domain.com  -d www.domain.com
volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: website-opt/views/
      o: bind

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://domain:3000;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are the external volume paths relative to the docker compose context path?

Comment: no and that is the problem I tried a lot of ways to link it, but I couldn't. So I thought the problem is my Docker files